# 数値計算の関数 / max()

Tags: python

大きいほうの値を表示したいのですが

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'
```

と出てしまいます。どうしたらよいでしょか？

```
n_string =input('整数を入力：'), input('整数を入力：')
n_int=int(n_string)
n=max(n_int)
print(n)
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！ご質問のコードを画像で貼ると、回答者がコードをコピーして回答のために使用する時や、同じような悩みを持つ他の人が検索する時に困ってしまいます。ぜひ今後は画像ではなくテキストを貼り付けて質問してください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n_string = input('整数を入力：'), input('整数を入力：')`の処理で2つの値を入力(input)すると、`n_string`は[タプル](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)という複数個の値を同時に持つ変数になります。

例えば実行時に下記の入力をするとします。

> 整数を入力：1
> 整数を入力：3

その直後に`print(n_string)`を実行した場合、`('1', '3')`が表示されます。
数字1つならば`int('1')`の構文で数値変換できるのですが、タプルでは`int(('1', '3'))`の構文となってしまうため、プログラムは数値変換をできずにご質問のエラーメッセージを英語で教えてくれます。

対策としては`n_string[0]`と書くとタプルの1個目を、`n_string[1]`で2個目を取ってきてくれるので、下記のコードで意図通りに動かすことができます。

```
n_string = input('整数を入力：'), input('整数を入力：')
print(n_string)  # ('1', '3') などのタプルが表示される

n_int=int(n_string[0]),int(n_string[1]) # タプルのそれぞれの項目を数値変換する
n=max(n_int)
print(n)
```